# split key column and move part to value columns

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark

I have an RDD

```
res8: (String,(String,String)) = (CUST1#NODE1#16,(callduration,1))
```

I need to transform this as

```
(String,(String,String,String)) = (CUST1#NODE1,(16,callduration,1))
```

Please show me the spark scala code for this transformation.

Comment: Please show what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on the last `#` with regex `#(?=[^#]*$)`. In case you are not familiar with regex, `?=` is a look ahead syntax, `[^#]` is a character class that matches any character except for `#` and `*` is quantifier which means 0 or more, `$` matches the end of string, so combined together, `[^#]*$` matches a pattern from the end of string which doesn't contain any `#`, which makes `#(?=[^#]*$)` matches the last `#` in the string;

After the first element is split by the last `#`, you can reconstruct the tuple with split elements.

Given a tuple:

```
val t = ("CUST1#NODE1#16",("callduration","1"))
// t: (String, (String, String)) = (CUST1#NODE1#16,(callduration,1))

t match {
    case (x, y) => {
        val Array(l, r) = x.split("#(?=[^#]*$)")
        (l, (r, y._1, y._2))
    }
}
// res8: (String, (String, String, String)) = (CUST1#NODE1,(16,callduration,1))
```

Given a rdd, the procedure is similar, you can map the above transformation on `rdd`:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(t))

rdd.map(_ match {
    case (x, y) => {
        val Array(l, r) = x.split("#(?=[^#]*$)")
        (l, (r, y._1, y._2))
}}).collect

// res11: Array[(String, (String, String, String))] = Array((CUST1#NODE1,(16,callduration,1)))
```